# segmentation fault when saving pandas dataframe to disk with to_hdf

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save a dataframe to disk using hdf5 format. 
Even this simple piece of code gives me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

```
import pandas as pd
import tables

df=pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3],index=['a','b','c','d'])

df.to_hdf('test.h5','test',mode='w',format='table')
```

The problem seems to be the table-format. In fixed-mode it runs fine. I tried python 2.7.11+ and 3.5.1+ and am running pandas 0.18.1. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what version of pytables are you running and how exactly did you install it? Also what OS?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and tables in version 3.2.2. It was installed via pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a newer version of PyTables. Version 3.2.3.1 does the job perfectly.